# VB.Net MDI Child in Number

Tags: vb.net, mdi

How many No of Forms can possible to open inside the MDI form in VB.net ..Is there any restriction is there

In my project suddenly close if am open lot of forms

Comment: How many forms do you think the average human can deal with at once?

Comment: You're only limited by the amount of memory your program has. More complex forms take up more memory of course.